# Why don't I see the option to make voice / video calls on WhatsApp Web Application on laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, whatsapp

I use WhatsApp Web version 2.2310.5 which I downloaded from the web (which is why Modify option is blacked out). I can access it from settings, and view it from my Taskbar.

[image: ![Image]

[image]

I used to get the option to make voice calls, but now I do not get the same option, nor can I receive voice calls.

[image]

I use an older version of WhatsApp since the I am more comfortable with the UI, and I can still select / forward  / delete multiple messages at once (which I cannot do in the updated version of WhatsApp).

Recently, I encountered some problems with this older version, where it would restart every time my computer would go to sleep after inactivity. I managed to find a solution, which was changing the Compatibility of WhatsApp Web desktop application from Windows 8 to Windows Vista Service Pack 2.

Image

This fixed all my problems, and Whatsapp Web worked well until I realised that I could not make or receive voice calls. I immediately changed it back to Windows 8 and restarted my PC, but the problem was not fixed.

I then ran a troubleshooter for Compatibility, it gives this.

[image]

What changes do I make to ensure that Whatsapp Web on Desktop runs properly, and that I can make and receive calls again?

Comment: Older applications may not use the correct protocols to talk to servers that have been updated to newer versions or feature sets. The servers may simply refuse certain types of connections. The may work in part or not at all depending on how they are implemented. You may have to bite the bullet and update to a supported version.